# Roboletric test error on Android Studio

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, robolectric

I am trying to set up the robolectric unit testing environment on Android Studio. I followed the steps here:

http://www.peterfriese.de/android-testing-with-robolectric/

I modified the build.gradle file as describled in the document and sync the project. It did built successfully and the junit and roboelctric jars appear in the external library in Android Studio IDE. However when I ran

./robolectric test

I saw the errors:

```
package org.junit.runner does not exist
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
```

...

However the package does exists in external library, why this error still happens? I checked my project source tree but I cannot find the jars in the project. Where does gradle put the downloaded jars?